# How can I wrap a spiral curve around an object?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to combine information about original position with information I get from proxymity node, to "wrap" object with spiral curve. Unfotunately for some reason it doesnt work 100% right, there are some places where curve just doesn't follow target. Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas how I can fix this setup?
[image: Nodes and result]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't specify a direction with The Geometry Proximity node. It will compute the closest geometry element to each vertex.

Here's what happens :

[image]

Some vertices are not pulled in the XY plane because the target geometry that is closest to it is higher or lower on the Z axis. Thus the artifacts.

What you can do with the spiral curve, is to use the [Raycast](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/raycast.html) node which takes a field direction input. Taking the opposite of the position of the vertex and projecting it on the Z = 0 plane will wrap the spiral correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: lovely!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, I had a suspicion about proximity, but wasn't able to wrap my mind around it) Your approach is amazing, thank you!